# QGIS 3.4.4 edit rendering styles for outputs - styles not loading

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, style, qgis-modeler

I have created a processing model in version 3.4.4 and I want the shapefile outputs from the model to load in a chosen style. I have saved the style files and used the  'edit rendering styles for outputs' to point to the relevant style files. However, when running the model they do not load with the correct styles. They load with a randomly selected style. I previously used a similar model in version 2.14 and the styles loaded correctly.

Is this a bug in 3.4?

Comment: It works fine for QGIS 3.8, perhaps download the latest version and test it again? When you created your style files for a specific geometry type, are the outputs of your model the same geometry?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't install the latest version (3.4 is the only approved version for my organisation). The geometry types are the same. My style files were stored on a server so other users can access them, I tried storing the styles locally (C drive) but it still didn't load correctly. I've even created basic buffer models to test this, just in case it was an issue with my more complex model, but the basic buffer mode again loaded with the incorrect layer style.

Comment: Could you add the `Set style for vector layer` tool at the end of your model to style your final output layer?

Comment: Thank you! That has resolved my problem.

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped :). Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method could be to add the `Set style for vector layer` tool at the end of your model which should apply the specific style to your final output.